# How to overwrite a service that may or may not exist in another library?

Tags: angular

There is some service exported by some library that I want to overwrite. I would do it like so:

```
import { BadService } from 'bad-library';
import { GoodService } from './good-service'

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: BadService, useValue: GoodService }
    ]
})
export class AppModule { ...
```

But the catch is that I don't really know if the bad service is in the library. My clients have multiple versions of the `bad-library` and some are using the version with `BadService`, and some use the version without it. I want my app to handle both cases, so if there is a `BadService`, then I want to overwrite it like above.

I tried to do something like this:

```
import * as BadLibrary from 'bad-library';
import { GoodService } from './good-service'

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        'BadService' in BadLibrary ? { provide: BadLibrary['BadService'], useValue: GoodService } : []
    ]
})
export class AppModule { ...
```

But I get the following error:
`"export 'BadService' (imported as 'BadLibrary') was not found in 'bad-library'`

I'm using Angular version 11.1.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try someone like this?

```
 providers: [BadLibraryService,
    {
      provide: BadService,
      useFactory: (BadLibraryService) => {
        return BadLibraryService.version >= '1.0.1'
          ? new BadService()
          : new GoodService();
      },
      deps: [BadLibraryService],
    },
  ],
```